# Nested SQL-Query with order by is very slow with index

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, sqlanywhere

I have the problem, that an sql query is very slow, if i sort over a datetime column in sybase sql anywhere. For example i have the following simple statement:

```
select * from documents order by createdatetime desc
```

In our application we generate outer sql statements, if the user sorts on columns in the grid views. For example if he sort ascending or descending on the `updatedatetime` columnm, the following statement will be generated:

1. `select s.* from (select * from documents order by createdatetime desc) s order by updatedatetime desc`
2. `select s.* from (select * from documents order by createdatetime desc) s order by updatedatetime asc`

In our database, we have ascending and descending indices on `createdatetime` and `updatedatetime`, but only one sorting is fast. We recognized the following behaviour:

1. If we create the ascending index at first, ascending sorting is fast
2. If we create the descending idnex at first, descending sorting is fast

I i take a look at the execution plan, sybase seems to take the correct index for executing.

Does any one has an idea? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand exactly, what indexes you have. Four single indexes on `createdatetime asc/desc` and `updatedatetime asc/desc`, or two composite indexes `createdatetime desc, updatedatetime asc` and `createdatetime desc, updatedatetime desc`?

Comment: i have 4 single indices.

Comment: Sorry, I have no explanation for this. It shouldn't even matter whether a single-column index is ascending or descending. At least according to these two links: http://dcx.sybase.com/1001/en/dbrfen10/rf-create-index-statement.html and http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/5485/is-it-useful-to-have-ascending-descending-index. For your query *one* index only, on `updatedatetime` (as the inner sort by `createdatetime` shouldn't even be executed for being overridden by the outer sort anyhow) should suffice.